Access to directory is tricky in Matlab
I have a Matlab code under this form:
clear all; close all; clc; clear variables;
folder = fileparts(which(mfilename)); 

% Add that folder plus all subfolders to the path.
addpath(genpath(folder));
data_folder="D:\Trucmuche\2024";

proportion_list=[1, 11];
mixing_times_list=["000", "015", "030", "060", "120"];


for i=1:length(proportion_list)
    this_prop=proportion_list(i);
    for j=1:length(mixing_times_list)
        rehash;
        this_mixing_time=mixing_times_list(j);
        browse_and_filter(data_folder, this_prop,this_mixing_time);
        disp("Success ! Moving to the next one !");
    end
end

and the function is
function browse_and_filter(root_folder, this_prop, this_mix_time)
    
    if isfolder(root_folder)
        disp(['Great ! The folder "', root_folder, '" exists.']);
    else
        disp(['Bad :-( The folder "', root_folder, '" does not exist.']);
    end
    
    % Get all rank_1 directories in the root folder
    rank_1_dirs = dir(root_folder);
    rank_1_dirs = rank_1_dirs([rank_1_dirs.isdir] & ~startsWith({rank_1_dirs.name}, '.'));
    disp({rank_1_dirs.name});
    ...

The problem is that, for the (two, but this even seems inconsistent) first iterations in the main code (the "ij" loop let's say), this works well and I get the following:

"Great ! The folder ""    "D:\Trucmuche\2024"    "" exists."


{'0716'}    {'0717'}    {'0718'}    {'0719'}

where these lasts are the (expected) outcome of disp({rank_1_dirs.name});
However, at some iteration, for some reason I don't understand, I get this

"Great ! The folder ""    "D:\Trucmuche\2024"    "" exists."

but the next line (i.e. the list of subfolders) remains empty which is not what I expect...
There are surely workarounds to alleviate this since the outcome is the same at every iteration of the loop, I can refactor the code but still I was wondering why do I have this inconsistent behaviour ? I am doing a write operation at the end of the code of each iteration but not in "D:\Trucmuche\2024". Also, I added a one second pause after each iteration to alleviate the possible effect of writing operations but this did nothing.
Any clue about that ?

What is happening in your  browse_and_filter function after the call to disp({rank_1_dirs.name});?

@BillBokeey A lot of computation on the files in the subfolders of rank_1_dirs

Please re-read [mre]. You show us parts of the code that produce the problem, not the full code. You need to remove parts of your code you think are not relevant to the problem, then run your code again to verify it still causes your problem. Then you can post that reduced code here.

Unrelated: don’t use clear all. clear, by itself, clears all variables from the workspace. clear all also unloads all functions you’ve used previously, which only serves to slow MATLAB down the next time you call those functions. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html — Also, clear variables is the same as clear.

Have you done what Cris suggested (i.e., verifying that the problem does not come from some code that you did not include in your question)? The code you posted cannot be the source of your problem, since it does the same thing for any i or j value
